# Zooming using getLayerExtent property of MapFrame not always zooming using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, zoom, definition-query

To see this problem:

1. Start ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0 (or any version you wish to test)
2. Create a new project using the Map template, call it TestProject in C:\temp and tick the checkbox to make a new folder
3. Add one layer only, so that our code can assume it will be the first one in the map.  I used the Natural Earth ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp but any feature class should do.
4. Insert one Layout, and one Map Frame into that Layout using the Map we just made with one Layer (besides the basemap)
5. Save the project and close ArcGIS Pro
6. Copy the code below into a script called test.py

---

```
import arcpy,os
 
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\TestProject\TestProject.aprx")

mapx = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
lyr = mapx.listLayers()[0]
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("Layout")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT', "Map Frame")[0]
 
lyr.definitionQuery = "NAME = 'Germany'"
mf.camera.setExtent(mf.getLayerExtent(lyr))
 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\temp\test.pdf")
os.startfile(r"C:\temp\test.pdf")
```

---

7. Set lyr.definitionQuery to be a valid expression - I used "NAME = 'Germany'" to filter my layer to the country named Germany
8. Run the code outside of ArcGIS Pro which I did from IDLE and you should see a test.pdf which is a map of Germany (or whatever you used) open in your default PDF viewer - I used Adobe Acrobat).  **Make sure to close the PDF viewer after you've seen the PDF to prevent it locking below**
9. Open the TestProject in ArcGIS Pro
10. Add test.py as a New Python Script tool into the TestProject's default toolbox (TestProject.atbx since I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0) - I let the tool's name default to Script and I gave it no parameters
11. Run the Python Script tool you just added.  The PDF that opens has filtered correctly but the extent is set to the whole layer

How can I get my tool to work the same within ArcGIS Pro as it does outside from a Python IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that this might be a bug introduced by ArcGIS Pro 3.0.0 but when I also tested at ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3 the same issue occurs there too.  Consequently, I think that it is a bug that may have been introduced a few dot releases back.  I am confident that it was working correctly at ArcGIS Pro 2.0.0 (I recorded a video using this code at that version for Udemy) so I think it was broken somewhere between 2.0.0 and 2.9.3.

To workaround it you could change:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\temp\TestProject\TestProject.aprx")
```

to be:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
```

Alternatively, if you need to run your tool outside of the project you used to author the map and layout that is used by the code, then the original code will work as-is, *as long as you run it from another project*.

To see that:

1. Close the PDF and ArcGIS Pro
2. Start ArcGIS Pro and create a new project without a template
3. Add test.py as a New Python Script tool into the projects Default.atbx - I let the tool's name default to Script and I gave it no parameters
4. Run the Python Script tool you just added. The PDF that opens has filtered correctly and has the correct extent

Answer (score 1):

I've had some similar problems with arcpy honoring the extent of a feature class. The same code in the Python window of ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5 works as expected but fails to zoom properly in a .py file used in a .pyt toolbox.

Looking at the "issues addressed" for 3.0 there's a bug that sounds similar:

> BUG-000147465 The camera.setExtent script does not zoom to a layer
> correctly in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.